# Changing ResultSetType Mode in Hibernate/JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, db2, java-stream, hikaricp

I have the following problem:

This is my Repository implementation for a given

```
public class SearchRepoImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>  implements SearchRepo<T,ID> {

    private final EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Stream<T> findStreamBySpec(Specification<T> where, Integer limit, Class<T> clazz) {
        final Class<T> domainClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(domainClass);


        applySpecificationToCriteria(where, domainClass, query); // this method does the necessary preprocessing and is of no interest
        return em.createQuery(query)
                .getResultStream()
                .limit(limit.longValue());
    }
}
```

However when I call this implementation using `searchRepo.findStreamBySpec(spec, 100, MyClass.class).forEach(e-> {...})` I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not determine if
>   resultset is empty due to exception calling isBeforeFirst or
>   isAfterLast()

I've managed to track down the issue down to a decompiled line of code inside DB2 driver:

```java
private final void checkThatResultSetTypeIsScrollable() throws SQLException {
   if (this.resultSetType_ == ResultSet.FORWARD_ONLY) {
      throw hd.a(this, this.agent_.logWriter_, ErrorKey.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED_ON_FORWARD_ONLY_CURSOR, "10900");
   }
}
```

This method, in turn, is called from HikariProxyResultSet

```java
    public boolean isBeforeFirst() throws SQLException {
        this.agent_.systemMonitor_.c();

        boolean var2;
        try {
            if (this.agent_.loggingEnabled()) {
                this.agent_.logWriter_.traceEntry(this, "isBeforeFirst");
            }

            this.checkForClosedResultSet();
            this.checkThatResultSetTypeIsScrollable();
          //^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ calls above method checkThatResultSetTypeIsScrollable()
            boolean var1 = this.isBeforeFirstX();
            if (this.agent_.loggingEnabled()) {
                this.agent_.logWriter_.traceExit(this, "isBeforeFirst", var1);
            }

            var2 = var1;
        } finally {
            this.agent_.systemMonitor_.a(this.statement_);
        }

        return var2;
    }
```

which was called from

```java
    private boolean isResultSetEmpty() {
        try {
            return currentPosition == 0 && !getResultSet().isBeforeFirst() && 
!getResultSet().isAfterLast();
                                         //^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ calls above method  isBeforeFirst()           
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw getSession().getFactory().getSQLExceptionHelper().convert(
                    e,
                    "Could not determine if resultset is empty due to exception calling isBeforeFirst or isAfterLast()"
            );
        }
    }
```

---

My question is, is there a way to hint or suggest to Hibernate, HikariCP and/or DB2 that I don't want to either set `ResultSet` to `FORWARD_ONLY` or that I don't want to use that kind of Scrollable result.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call your repository from a service and wrap it with @Transactional

```
@Service
public class MyService {

private final SearchRepoImpl searchRepoImpl;

@Transactional
public void findStreamBySpec(){
 // wrapping up this method with transactional annotation is crucial for streams to work.
 searchRepoImpl.findStreamBySpec()
}

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).